# Redirect double-slash "//" URLs using a rewrite rule in the .htaccess file

Tags: seo, google-search-console, htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite

Google Search Console is giving me the *Duplicate without user-selected canonical* error for URLs that contain an unnecessary double slash `//` in them, like:

```
https://university.edu/~user//dir/
```

To avoid defining a canonical URL in the head of every `index.html` file on the site, it would be nice to just add a [URL rewriting rule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) in my `.htaccess` file that would redirect all URLs with such a double-slash (not the initial double-slash after the `https:` though) to the corresponding URL with a single slash. Is there are rewrite rule that would do this? And would this appease Google Search Console?

Comment: It looks like you are using [Apache per-user web directories](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html), in which case. the double slash you are seeing is effectively at the _start_ of the URL-path you would normally define in your application when constructing internal anchors/URLs. So you should check your HTML/code to see how your internal links are constructed.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, it is better to create a redirect instead of setting a canonical tag, especially if these are really just technical duplicates.

I would also recommend finding out how Google knows about the duplicates. If the cause is on the website itself, it should be fixed also.

Here is an example rule for rewriting duplicate slashes in URLs to a single slash (the slashes after the `https:` are ignored). Please test the rule yourself for possible conflicts with other rules already defined in the `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: "duplicate trailing slashes" - the rule removes "duplicate slashes" anywhere in the URL-path, not just "trailing" slashes (that occur at the _end_ of the URL-path). I've removed the 3 instances of "trailing" from your answer. (+1)